# Why different scopes for my elements?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I am relatively new to AngularJS. I have to populate a list using a result of the Ajax call, but I have checked that the elements are in different scope.

```
   <ng-form class="ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-required" name="fleetForm">
    <a target="_blank" href=".....">Click to verify your log type.</a>
    <select class="ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-required" required="" ng-options="...." ng-model="test.fleet">
    <fg-test-widget class="ng-isolate-scope ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="test-model" horizontal="false">
</ng-form>
```

Comment: You state you're populating a list ... but the "HTML" appears to be rendering a form. How are you determining that the above HTML is creating new scope? Many directives in Angular will create a new scope (`ng-if`, `ng-repeat`, `ng-include`, etc.) but I don't see you using any of them.

Comment: Updated my code to reflect the html. I have checked the scopes for my elements using Java Script and they are in different scopes.

Comment: Thanks, now the problem is obvious. You can see from the CSS classes that Angular adds to elements, that your `fg-test-widget` directive is creating an isolate scope. We usually use isolate scopes in directives because they are re-usable components and we don't want them interfering w/each other.